# Python3 - import and override method

Tags: python, sockets, import, overriding

In `server.py` I have two classes, class `Server` and `ClientThread` with method `processCmd`. I want to override this method when I import this code to my new Proxy class.
How to do it?

This is server.py:

```
class ClientThread( threading.Thread, socket.socket ):
    #(some code)
    def processCmd( self, cmd ):
        if 'quit' == cmd:
            self.writeline(str('Ok, bye'))
            QUIT = True
            done = True
        elif 'bye' == str(cmd):
            self.writeline(str('Ok, bye'))
            done = True
        else:
            print(cmd)
#
class Server:
    #(some code)
    def run( self ):
       self.sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
       self.sock.bind( ( '127.0.0.1', 5050 ) )
       new_thread = ClientThread( client )
       print('Incoming Connection. Started thread ', end=' ')
       self.thread_list.append( new_thread )
       new_thread.start()
```

and in another file is main code:

```
import server
#
class Proxy( server.Server):
    def processCmd( self, cmd ):
        if 'quit' == cmd:
            self.writeline(str('Another quit'))
            QUIT = True
            done = True
        elif 'bye' == str(cmd):
            self.writeline(str('Another bye'))
            done = True
        else:
            print(cmd)
    pass
```

Comment: I cant see `processCmd` method in class `Server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the `processCmd` method in the `Server` class. You're going to have to import `ClientThread` as well and subclass it.

```
import server

class Proxy( server.Server):
    def run( self ):
       self.sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
       self.sock.bind( ( '127.0.0.1', 5050 ) )
       new_thread = CustomClientThread( client )
       print('Incoming Connection. Started thread ', end=' ')
       self.thread_list.append( new_thread )
       new_thread.start()
    pass

class CustomClientThread(server.ClientThread)
    def processCmd( self, cmd ):
        #override here
```

---

And if you don't want to override the whole `run` method you should alter it in your base-class so the type of clientThread can be set out side of the method.

```
class Server:
    thread = ClientThread

    #(some code)
    def run( self ):
       self.sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
       self.sock.bind( ( '127.0.0.1', 5050 ) )
       new_thread = thread( client )
       print('Incoming Connection. Started thread ', end=' ')
       self.thread_list.append( new_thread )
       new_thread.start()
```

Then the subclass just looks like this, and the `run` method stays the same.

```
class Proxy( server.Server):
    thread = CustomClientThread
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have changed:  new_thread = ClientThread(client) to  thread = ClientThread and new_thread = thread( client ), but I have problem with start old ClientThread process

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override method from `ClientThread` then you can override as

```
class OverrideClientThread(server.ClientThread):
    def processCmd(self, cmd):
        # call super
        server.ClientThread.processCmd(self, cmd)
        #do something.
```